# Param for spinners

Tags: android, parameters

I'm trying to insert data from a spinner into a database. A beginner in Android so help will be appreciated.
Here's the function:

```
public JSONObject order(Spinner name, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", order_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(orderURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }
```

The error i get on **params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));** is

*"The constructor BasicNameValuePair(String, Spinner) is undefined, One quick fix available. Change type of name to String".*

Comment: public JSONObject order(Spinner name, String email, String password) try to change Spinner name to String name

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
public JSONObject order(Spinner name, String email, String password){
```

To :

```
public JSONObject order(String name, String email, String password){
```

Answer (score 0):

A spinner is a ui component which you can't put in JSON. You have to get the value from the spinner.

Comment: How does one do that?

Comment: How does one insert data from a spinner into a database?